# T-SQL change time part of a DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a stored procedure and I passing it a this parameters:

Now how can I change the time part in the `@filterDateFrom` and `@filterDateTo` to set to `@filterTimeFrom`  and `@filterTimeTo` .

here is the whole stored procedure

```
USE [DBName]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AdminGetAdminBusinessLogList]    Script Date: 1/3/2014 12:17:53 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdminGetAdminBusinessLogList]
@UserContextUserId INT, 
@UserContextCompanyId INT, 
@UserContextSessionId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
@UserContextProcessId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@UserContextIPAddress NVARCHAR (100),
@filterDateFrom DATETIME, 
@filterDateTo DATETIME, 
@filterAffectedCompanyId INT, 
@filterUserId INT, 
@FilterEventIdTableType FilterEventIdTableType READONLY, 
@filterTableName NVARCHAR(100), 
@filterEntityId INT,
@filterTimeFrom INT,
@filterTimeTo INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC CheckRights @UserContextUserId, NULL, @@PROCID

        DECLARE @MaxRowCount INT
        SELECT @MaxRowCount = CAST([Value] AS INT) FROM Configuration WHERE [Key] = 'System.Sql.MaxRowCount'


        DECLARE @EventIdTableTypeCount INT
        SET @EventIdTableTypeCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @FilterEventIdTableType)

        SET @filterDateFrom = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@filterDateFrom AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME);
        SET @filterDateFrom = DATEADD(hh, @filterTimeFrom, @filterDateFrom);

        SET @filterDateTo = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@filterDateTo AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME);
        SET @filterDateTo = DATEADD(hh, @filterTimeTo, @filterDateTo);

        CREATE TABLE #Temp
        (
            [Id] INT NOT NULL
            PRIMARY KEY (Id)                        
        )

        SET ROWCOUNT @MaxRowCount

        --Temp table
      IF (@filterTableName IS NULL OR @filterTableName = '')
        BEGIN
         INSERT INTO #Temp      
            SELECT
                BusinessLog.Id
            FROM
                dbo.BusinessLog  
            WHERE
                (@filterDateFrom IS NULL OR EventDate >= @filterDateFrom) AND 
                (@filterDateTo IS NULL OR EventDate < @filterDateTo) AND
                (@filterAffectedCompanyId IS NULL OR (UserContextCompanyId = @filterAffectedCompanyId OR AffectedCompanyId = @filterAffectedCompanyId)) AND
                (@filterUserId  IS NULL OR BusinessLog.UserContextUserId = @filterUserId) AND
                (@UserContextIPAddress IS NULL OR UserContextIPAddress LIKE @UserContextIPAddress + '%') AND
                (@EventIdTableTypeCount = 0 OR BusinessLog.EventId IN (SELECT Value FROM @FilterEventIdTableType))
        END

      ELSE

        BEGIN
         INSERT INTO #Temp      
            SELECT
                BusinessLog.Id
            FROM
                dbo.BusinessLog  
            INNER JOIN dbo.AuditLog ON AuditLog.BusinessLogId = BusinessLog.Id
            WHERE
                (AuditLog.TableName = @filterTableName AND AuditLog.EntityId = @filterEntityId)
        END     

        --ROWCOUNT visszaállítása
        SET ROWCOUNT 0

        --BusinessLog       
        SELECT
            BusinessLog.Id, EventId, Audience, EventDate, UserContextUserId, UserAccount.UserFullName AS UserContextUserFullName,  UserContextCompanyId, cForUserContext.Name AS UserContextCompanyName, AffectedCompanyId, cForAffected.Name AS AffectedCompanyName, UserContextIPAddress, UserAccount.UserUniqueId AS UserContextUserUniqueId, BusinessLog.MessageFormatVersion
        FROM
            dbo.BusinessLog
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Company cForAffected ON cForAffected.Id = BusinessLog.AffectedCompanyId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Company cForUserContext ON cForUserContext.Id = BusinessLog.UserContextCompanyId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.UserAccount ON UserAccount.Id = BusinessLog.UserContextUserId
        INNER JOIN #Temp ON #Temp.Id = BusinessLog.Id

        --BusinessLogParameter
        SELECT
            BusinessLogId, IsResource, Value
        FROM
            dbo.BusinessLogParameter
        INNER JOIN #Temp ON #Temp.Id = BusinessLogParameter.BusinessLogId
        ORDER BY #Temp.Id ASC

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @error NVARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @severity INT

        SELECT @error = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SELECT @severity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

        RAISERROR (@error, @severity, 1)
    END CATCH
END
```

Thanks

Comment: How do the filterTimeFrom and filterTimeTo parameters relate to time? Are they seconds, minutes?

Comment: And why not pass the time part with the date in the first two parameters?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: we are using a custom date picker controll that hasn't a time value, so I need to ad it manualy, dont ask more

Comment: OK, but what units are the 2 time parameters in?

Comment: No, the filterTimeFrom and filterTimeTo that are declared as ints.

Comment: they come from a ListBox, sorry, I missunderstood the question, they are whole hours

Answer (score 1):

First remove any existing time portion from the @filterDateFrom variable

```
SET @filterDateFrom = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@filterDateFrom AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Then add the hours portion to the date

```
SET @filterDateFrom = DATEADD(hh, @filterTimeFrom, @filterDateFrom)
```

Repeat the process for the "to" variables

Comment: Can you explain what in what way it doesn't work. Do you get an error? Does it not give you the answer you were expecting?

Comment: I'm sorry but you're going to need to explain it a lot more than that